# Does Android provide a getSpeechRate() method for TextToSpeech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

The [official Android documentation on text-to-speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) includes information on the [setSpeechRate() method.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setSpeechRate(float))

I would like to determine what settings the user has already made, so that I can respect these and can add pauses in a long speech whose length is proportional to the overall speed of the speaking voice.

Is there an equivalent `getSpeechRate()` method?

One possible workaround would be to detect how long it takes to play a benchmark speech, and compare that to the time it takes to play the same speech when the speech rate is set to 1.0. However, there are many potential sources of error in this technique, so I would prefer to use an official method, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/SynthesisRequest.html#getSpeechRate()

Check the onSynthesizeText(SynthesisRequest, SynthesisCallback) method in the API

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.